# How to Filter Date and Time Simultaneously in Excel Using Specific Range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hy, I am trying to filter time and then date simultaneously inserted into two different columns. Both are working fine separately but when I used them together, only one filed is applied. I am using following sheet.

[image]

I am using following Button Code:
Button Filter Time:

```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim lngStart As Long, lngEnd As Long
   Sheets("Location").Select
   lngStart = Range("C4").Value 'assume this is the start date
   lngEnd = Range("C6").Value 'assume this is the end date
   ActiveSheet.Range("$C$8:$C$10712").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("C4").Value, 
   Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Range("C6").Value   
   End Sub
```

and below the give code is used for Button "Filter Date"

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim lngStart As Long, lngEnd As Long
   
   Sheets("Location").Select
   lngStart = Range("D4").Value 'assume this is the start date
   lngEnd = Range("D6").Value 'assume this is the end date
   ActiveSheet.Range("$D$8:$D$10712").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("D4").Value, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Range("D6").Value
   
End Sub
```

Button buttons are working fine but only one button work at the same time. For example I want to filter the time from 11:30:00 AM to 2:32:00 PM and Date from 1/2/2020 to 1/8/2020. I will first click on the Time which will successfully filtered, but when I click on the Filter Date, it only filter the first date 1/2/2020. Please check where I am doing wrong. thanks

Comment: To figure it out yourself, record a macro while applying the filter.  But it appears as if you are not including the entire range `$C$8:$C$10712` when you are using the date filter (in which case you'd be filtering on `Field:=2`)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I used the same setting but it give me an error of Field then I change it from 2 to 1

Comment: `Field` is not a VBA error message with which I am familiar.  So can't help you with that.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks brother its working.... Actually I was using single column range....